socket connect even if host unavailable (not existing)
I'm try to understand why
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(tool.getHost(), tool.getPortTool()), timeout);
dosn't print an exception if the host dosn't exists.
package esempioSocket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import esempioSocket.Tool;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Tool tool = new Tool("10.39.188.101", 6653);

        System.out.println("reachele 1: " + tool.isReachable() );
        
        int timeout = 1500;

        Socket socket = new Socket();
        System.out.println("after new: " + socket);

        try {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(tool.getHost(), tool.getPortTool()), timeout);
            System.out.println("after connect: " + socket);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("run() - UnknownHostException - tool: " + tool.getHost() + ":" + tool.getPortTool());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("run() - IOException - tool: " + tool.getHost() + ":" + tool.getPortTool());
        }

        if (socket.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("after isConnect: " + socket);
            tool.setReachable(true);
            try {
                socket.close();
                System.out.println("after close: " + socket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("run() - socket close() " + e);
            }
        } else {
            tool.setReachable(false);
        }
        
        System.out.println("reachele: " + tool.isReachable() );
        System.out.println("last line: " + socket);
        
        
    }
}   

and the class tools is
public class Tool {

    private String host;
    private Integer  portTool;
    private boolean reachable;

    
    Tool(String h, Integer port) {
        this.host=h;
        this.portTool=port;
    }

........
set and getter 

And if i run ping, or telnet or tracert from command line I get no success (as it should be) (telnet after some time give back my prompt).
Also
netstat -an | find "10.39.188.101"

and
netstat -an | find "6653"

give me no result!
When I run the program I'm expecting that because the host is not existent the socket.connect give me an exception (or a message that the connection can't be established, instead I get the following result:
reachele 1: false
after new: Socket[unconnected]
after connect: Socket[addr=/10.39.188.101,port=6653,localport=64473]
after isConnect: Socket[addr=/10.39.188.101,port=6653,localport=64473]
after close: Socket[addr=/10.39.188.101,port=6653,localport=64473]
reachele: true
last line: Socket[addr=/10.39.188.101,port=6653,localport=64473]

If I change host to 11.39.188.101 i get:
reachele 1: false
after new: Socket[unconnected]
run() - IOException - tool: 11.39.188.101:6653
reachele: false
last line: Socket[unconnected]

As it should be!!!! host 11.39.188.101 is not existing but also 10.39.188.101 is not existing.
If I run netstat while the program is still running and socket.close has not reached:

arp:

tracert:

If I run the same example on a different pc (with different version of java), i get

If I use the same version of java in a different pc i get :

so the problem should be in the other pc, but why????

Are you sure it doesn't connect successfully?

it connect the result of my program is:reachele 1: false
reachele: true

So? I don't understand the question. The host is obviously not unreachable.

but the connection do not print an exception in other words the connection cannot be establish and the method socket.isConnected() return true (like the connection was made)

but the connection do not print an exception in other words the connection cannot be establish What? It doesn't print an exception because the socket connected successfully.

how is that possible if the host 10.39.188.101 dosn't exist in my network? my ip is 192.168.1.59

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The fact that you can’t ping doesn’t  prove that the host is unreachable. The fact that you can connect provides that it is not. Your question doesn’t make sense. You are complaining about success.

Don't use quote format for errors and logs. Note how it distorted what should be several lines of output. Use the same format as code for those.

Don't test connectivity to a port with ping. Use telnet or netcat, depending on what is available in your system.

No. Test connectivity to a port by trying to connect to the port, and then using the connection in the normal way. Any other technique amounts to trying to predict the future; tests the wrong thing; introduces timing windows; ... @aled

user207421 yes I'm complaining about success because I know there is no possibility of success. My question make sense because I need to verified if a tool is available, and if socket.connect give me that is available while I know it cannot be available is an issue that I have to resolve in order to do what I have to do. Sorry for my english

@Progman    this is the output    :
reachele 1: false
after new: Socket[unconnected]
after connect: Socket[addr=/10.39.188.101,port=6653,localport=63539]
after isConnect: Socket[addr=/10.39.188.101,port=6653,localport=63539]
after close: Socket[addr=/10.39.188.101,port=6653,localport=63539]
reachele: true
last line: Socket[addr=/10.39.188.101,port=6653,localport=63539]

@Progman I have include information in the question thx

"Unreachable", "not available", and "not existing" are three different conditions. Not the same condition. On the other hand, if you can connect to the host, it is (a) reachable, (b) available, and (c) existing. There are no two ways about this. The only problem here is your concept(s) of "unreachable", "not available", and "not existing", and the tools which you erroneously using to determine these conditions.

thanks, may be I choose the wrong word, the fact is exactely that "there are no two ways about this", but I'm at my home there is just a modem and my pc (also I have an address of class B, how I can reach an host with an IP of class A? also if I change the ip to 10.39.188.77 or 10.39.188.22 or 10.39.188.66 the result is the same, I can connect but it is unbelivable because I'm not in a firm network, I'm at my home. I used the tool I know ping netstat telnet, if there is one else I will try, but have you copied the example, and run it? it shoulb be give you the same result. anyway thanks a lot

I think that the fundamental problem here is that you are misunderstanding what a ping failure actually means.
Ping uses the ICMP protocol which is a separate protocol to TCP.  ICMP packets can be totally blocked by a firewall, or an ICMP response can be faked by a firewall. These are typically done when an organization wants to restrict external people from discovering information about the organization's networks.
This means that Ping cannot reliably distinguish between a host that doesn't exist, is turned off, and so on ... and a host that is fully functional but has ICMP blocked or spoofed by (typically) a firewall.
In your case:

ICMP for the host is blocked
TCP access to the host + port is not blocked.  And apparently, the host is accepting TCP connections.

The host is NOT unreachable.  If a socket connection to the host succeeds, then it is reachable by definition.

The corollary to this is that it is pointless to "ping" a host to decide whether not to try to connect to it.  Even using Socket.connect as a test and then calling Socket.connect again to make the connection "for real" is a bad idea.  (It introduces possible race conditions.)
Instead, an application should just connect and use the connection, and deal with any exceptions appropriately.

UPDATE
The fact that you are able to connect to that host means that it DOES exist.  As I noted in the comments, one possibility is that it is host is not on your network, and a second one is that it is on your network and you didn't realize it.
The screenshots that you added both conclusively1 show that the host you are connecting to is not on your network.

The arpd output demonstrates that the IP address doesn't have a local IP -> MAC address mapping.  That means that it is not local.

The traceroute output shows a route to that host is going via (at least) 2 routers.  (After the 2nd router, you are hitting a firewall that is dropping ICMP PING packets.)



1 - Conclusively ... unless your machine has been hacked and a rootkit has been installed that spoofs the arpd and traceroute output!

ok ping and socket.connect are different, thanks I get the concept; But my problem is different because I know there is no any other host in my network also my ip is 198.162.1.59, How I can connect to an host that not exist? I've reported a ping example but the issue is releted to the fact that host 10.39.188.101 is not in my network. may be my english need to be improved

Well ... clearly ... it DOES exist.  So maybe the host is not on your network, but the router knows where to route packets to it.  Or maybe it is on your network and you didn't realize it. Here's an idea: modify your Java prog to open the connection and then sleep for a long time.  While it is running use netstat -at to list all TCP connections, etc.

Another thing you can try is to use arp -a to figure out what the IP <-> MAX address mapping is for the unknown IP address.  And use traceroute 10.39.188.101 to see how the packets will be routed.

indeed i have already did the first test, launch the program in debug and put a breakpoint on the last line of code and while the program is still running, I have tried netstat, and in this case it give me result, I put the screen shot in the answer, also for command arp e tracert (I'm using windos). thanks so much!

The last two screenshots show that 10.39.188.101 is NOT on your local network; i.e.  the segment of your network on >your< side of the first router in the traceroute output.

ok, 10.39.188.101 is not in my local network; How you can explain that with socket.connect I can connect ? it is unbelievable right? can be a bug on java api? I cannot explain that is a host is not in my local network Ho I can connect with java api socket.connect, what's wrong in me?

I have also tried on a different PC with java 1.8, and there it works regulary (as you can see in the last screnshot), now I'm going to use the same version of java in the new PC, may be is java 7 that has a bug on socket.connect

I seriously doubt that this is a Java 7 bug.  I think that is saying that something is broken at the operating system or networking level for that specific machine or virtual machine.  But ... why are you using a version of Java that has been end-of-life for a long time?  (Since April 2015 if you are using a free / public release.)

"How you can explain that with socket.connect I can connect" - That is how IP protocols work.  In fact ... how the Internet works!  On my machine I can connect to (public) IP addresses on the other side of the world.  Now 10.* is a private address range.  But that just means that your organization or ISP has set up services to run on private IP addresses, and your router knows how to route IP packets to reach them.  This is normal networking stuff.  (Maybe you need to do some more background reading on how IP networking works ...)

By the way ... where did you get this particular IP address from?  What is it supposed to be running? Why is your application trying to connect to it?  This is sounding like an X Y Problem.

It is a test on my pc but seriously important to me, and not is not a java bug. Yes studing IP Networks can be a task to me. That IP is because it is associated with a tool that during this test is off (the tool has a battery that is not connected to it). If I turn it on it's normal to see it connected, but if I turn it off it's not normal

So ... you are saying that you can connect to the host even though the tool's battery is disconnected?   That means that the host must be getting power from ... somewhere other than the battery that you have disconnected. Alternatively, something is redirecting the traffic to that IP to something else.   The Java JVM won't do that AFAIK.  It would have to be something at the PC's operating system level or further out.  Get an expert to look at your PC to figure out what is going on.

you're right, I find out that when I use my cellphone as hotspot the program run and is able to connect (the tool is turn off, so it is inexplicable to me), but if I connet using a different networkm the program print an exception (IOException), so the problem is on the network but how I can discover why.

The problem is related to zscaler, in some way that I do not understand with zscaler enable the host 10.39.188.101 (and many other in the form 10.39.188.xx), disabling it and everything works fine.
To disable zscaler just follow the istrunction in:
ZScaler - cannot stop the service without passwords
